# problem after read data from database ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\r'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good Day everybody! Is there away to solve this problem **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\r'** im getting this problem after reading the data from mysql database, i have seen related post same problem ,  but its not working the solution with me such like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861594/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168035/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)
the data can be read successfully from database but the program stop into this line in the code **indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-2:])** : the code  working fine when i set the value direct but the problem happen when i read data from database.
suppose this data is store in database:

```
data=3669173122946610524661732905264584239464321015293887264584378370174699627442417573669172466172466172938871746993783703210153210152394642394641864073669176459629027117604963001838526185423176139908966

data=str(data)
def split(data):
    indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-2:]) 
    data = data[:-2]
    rv = []
    for i in indices[::-1]:
        rv.append(data[-i:])
        data=data[:-i]
    rv.append(data)
    return rv[::-1]
d1, d2, d3 = split(data)
```

i'm adding the reading data from database

```
    import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
   mySQLconnection1 = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='vcn',
                             user='vcn',
                             password='vcn')
   sql_select_Query = "select * from pid where id =56"
   cursor = mySQLconnection1 .cursor()
   cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
   records = cursor.fetchall()

   for row in records:

       data= row[1]

       print(data)

   cursor.close()

except Error as e :
    print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(mySQLconnection1 .is_connected()):
        mySQLconnection1.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

any suggestion!! thanks all

Comment: You say your data is coming in from sql, apparently it has an extra new line at the end. Use `.strip()` prior to parsing it to int

Comment: @G.Anderson I think db should not give `LF` or `CRLF` by default there should be some configuration problem or at data write `\n` and `\r` should be replaced by empty string

Comment: sorry, where i should mention .strip() in the cod?

Comment: @Mayur, im reading the data successfully from database but the problem happen when i pass the data into this code showing me that message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are getting `CRLF` from db just use `strip` function

```
data=3669173122946610524661732905264584239464321015293887264584378370174699627442417573669172466172466172938871746993783703210153210152394642394641864073669176459629027117604963001838526185423176139908966

data=str(data)
def split(data):
    data = data.strip()
    indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-2:]) 
    data = data[:-2]
    rv = []
    for i in indices[::-1]:
        rv.append(data[-i:])
        data=data[:-i]
    rv.append(data)
    return rv[::-1]
d1, d2, d3 = split(data)
```